# which one these would work CTE, case statement, coalesce

Tags: sql

I am trying to somehow consolidate the result of these select statemnts into one
I have two temp tables in a stored procedure table1, table2

Can someone help me with getting the output set to look like this,
Table1 is the base table. Consider first row in Table1 with Id = 1001.
If this Id = 1001 exists in Table2, then Final Output for id =1001 should have Isselected =  true and take the values from Table2
If it doesnt exist then leave as is.

I have things in my mind but can't get it to work. Using CTE, Case, coalesce??

```
Table1
id    Name   isselected userdefine1 userdefine2
1001  name1   0   
1002  name2   0   
1003  name3   0   

Table2
id     userdefine1  userdefine2
1001    helloworld   helloworld2

Final Output
id    Name   isselected  userdefine1   userdefine2
1001  name1   1           helloworld  helloworld2
1002  name2   0   
1003  name3   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a `LEFT JOIN` with a `CASE` statement around the `isselected`:

```
SELECT tbl1.Id,
tbl1.Name,
CASE WHEN tbl2.Id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as isselected,
tbl2.userdefine1,
tbl2.userdefine2
FROM tbl1
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.Id = tbl2.Id
```

Comment: thanks a lot. later on, when I looked at it, it looked like left join would it :). Thanks again